# daemontools: How to find out what is wrong?

Tags: debian, daemontools

I'm exploring daemontools to run some of our applications, which generate some output as well (on both stdout and stderr).

I installed daemontools on a debian box. Every time, I do a `svc -u /etc/service/myservice` to start the service, I get a `[defunct]` process. How can I go about debugging this problem.

Following is my `/etc/service/myservice/run`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec myservice -c /etc/myservice/myservice.conf
```

and `/etc/service/myservice/log/run`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec multilog t ./main
```

Any help would be apppreciated. Thanks.

Comment: More information are velcome. For example, what happens when you directly run /etc/service/myservice/run ?

Comment: It runs just fine, spewing out messages on the console (both stderr and stdout).

Comment: So try to run it with the same user as daemontools will use for it. This can also be a problem of environement: what happen if you run it from cron ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch some errors with `ps -aux | grep readproctitle`.

Some debugging ideas:

- `myserver` is not in the `PATH`. Consider specifying the full path to the program.
- `myserver` forks into background: This is explicitly forbidden with services started using daemontools.
- Permissions: Double-check the permissions of the directories and of the `run` script.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. When nothing else worked, this worked for me :

- Find the pid of svscanboot through `ps auxf`. You will see that it starts svscan which monitors all the services.
- `kill -9 -pid`.

svscanboot will start automatically and so will all services under svscan.

I faced the issue when named pipe of svcan gets corrupt when no disk space is left on machine.